# How to understand "The shards are replica sets."

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

When I put shard and Replica Set together, I am confused. 
Why does the reference say that the shards are replica sets? 
Do replica sets contains shards?
Can someone give me a conceptual explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replica Set is a cluster of MongoDB servers which implements Master - slave implementation. So, basically same data is shared between multiple replica i.e Master and Slave(s). Master is also termed as primary node and Slave(s) is/are considered as Secondary nodes. 
It replicates your data on multiple mongo instances to solve/avoid fail overs. MongoDB also perform election of Primary node between secondary nodes automatically whenever Primary node goes down.

Sharding is used to store large data set between multiple machines. So basically, if you simply wants to compare Sharded nodes doesnt/may not contain same data where as Relicated nodes contains same data.
Sharding has different purpose,large data set is spread accross multiple machines.

Now, this large data set's subset can also be replicated to multiple nodes as primary and secondary to overcome failovers. So basically a shard can have multiple replica-set. These replica set of a shard contains subset of data for a large data set. 
So, multiple shards can complete the whole large data set which are separated in the form of chunks. These chunks can be replicated within a Shard using Replica set.

You can also get more details related to this in MongoDB manual.

Answer (score 2):

Sharding happens one level above replication.

When you use both sharding and replication, your cluster consists of many replica-sets and one replica-set consists of many mongod instances.

However, it is also possible to create a cluster of stand-alone mongod instances which are not replicated or have only some shards implemented as replica-sets and some shards implemented as stand-alone mongod instances.

Answer (score 1):

Each shard is a replica set, not the shards are replica sets.

This is a language barrier, in English to say such a thing really means the same as "each shard is a replica set" in this context.

So to explain, say you have a collection of names a-z. Shard 1 holds a-b. This shard is also a replica set which means it has automated failover and replication of that range as well. So sharding in this sense is a top level term that comes above replica sets.

Comment: Server_A: shard_ holds a_e; Server_B: shard_ holds f_k;  Server_C: shard_ holds l_z;  when the Server_B down, f_k will be lost; how to use replication with this situation

Comment: @louis server b would be a replica set, when the primary of it fails a secondary will be elected to that position and you will regain that range

Answer (score 0):

Shards are used to break a collection and store parts of it in different places. It is not necessary that a shard be a replica set, it can be a single server, but to achieve reliability and avoid loss of data, a replica set can be used as a shard instead of a single server. So, if one of the servers in the replica set goes down, the others will still hold the data.

Comment: if the shard as replica sets,when the data is stored,it performs not sharding,but replication. Is this understanding ?

Comment: Yes, but within that shard. Not across the shards. So, you have replication inside a shard and sharding across the shards.